# How to read from a file using only readline()

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code i have right now is this

```
f = open(SINGLE_FILENAME)
lines = [i for i in f.readlines()]
```

but my proffessor demands that

You may use readline(). You may not use read(), readlines() or iterate over the open file using for.

any suggestions? 
thanks

Comment: note: `lines = f.readlines()` does the same (produces a list of lines). A lazy version: `lines = f` (file is an iterator over lines by itself). Where have you learned `lines = [i for i in f.readlines()]` (it doesn't make sense to use it)? I've seen such code several times and I'm interested what is the origin or the logic behind it.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a [two-argument `iter()` version](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter):

```
lines = iter(f.readline, "")
```

If you need a list of lines:

```
lines = list(lines)
```

Answer (score 3):

First draft:

```
lines = []
with open(SINGLE_FILENAME) as f:
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if line:
            lines.append(line)
        else:
            break
```

I feel fairly certain there is a better way to do it, but that does avoid iterating with for, using read, or using readlines.

You could write a generator function to keep calling `readline()` until the file was empty, but that doesn't really seem like a large improvement here.

Comment: This is, based on my experience, almost certainly what the professor wants; and coincidentally this situation is one of the best simple demonstrations you will find of the professor's incompetence.