# Filtering a CSV file in python

Tags: python, csv, formatting, bioinformatics

I have downloaded this [csv file](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gv/mhc/ihwg.cgi?cmd=page&user_id=0&probe_id=0&source_id=0&locus_id=0&locus_group=1&proto_id=0&kit_id=0&page=RAmain), which creates a spreadsheet of gene information. What is important is that in the `HLA-*` columns, there is gene information. If the gene is too low of a resolution e.g. `DQB1*03` then the row should be deleted. If the data is too high resoltuion e.g. `DQB1*03:02:01`, then the `:01` tag at the end needs to be removed. So, ideally I want to proteins to be in the format `DQB1*03:02`, so that it has two levels of resolution after `DQB1*`. How can I tell python to look for these formats, and ignore the data stored in them.
e.g.

```
if (csvCell is of format DQB1*03:02:01):
   delete the :01 # but do this in a general format
elif (csvCell is of format DQB1*03):
   delete row
else:
   goto next line
```

UPDATE: Edited code I referenced

```
import csv
import re
import sys

csvdictreader = csv.DictReader(open('mhc.csv','r+b'), delimiter=',')
csvdictwriter = csv.DictWriter(file('mhc_fixed.csv','r+b'), fieldnames=csvdictreader.fieldnames, delimiter=',')
csvdictwriter.writeheader()
targets = [name for name in csvdictreader.fieldnames if name.startswith('HLA-D')]

for rowfields in csvdictreader:
  keep = True
  for field in targets:
    value = rowfields[field]
    if re.match(r'^\w+\*\d\d$', value):
      keep = False
      break # quit processing target fields
    elif re.match(r'^(\w+)\*(\d+):(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)$', value):
      rowfields[field] = re.sub(r'^(\w+)\*(\d+):(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)$',r'\1*\2:\3', value)
    else: # reduce gene resolution if too high
              # by only keeping first two alles if three are present
      rowfields[field] = re.sub(r'^(\w+)\*(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)$',r'\1*\2:\3', value)
  if keep:
     csvdictwriter.writerow(rowfields)
```

Comment: Have you tried regular expressions to match the formats?  This sounds like something that can be accomplished by a map and a filter, with a regular expression.  Regular expressions to find the patterns, maps to delete the :01 and filters to delete the rows.

Comment: Also, would you provide a small snippet of input and the desired output?  Not everyone will want to navigate the link and dig through an Excel spreadsheet to fill in the pieces.

Comment: @user1161318 how would I write that line of regex to accomplish this?

Comment: @user1876508: Check this link out, for information on Python regular expressions: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: I can see some problems with the code you added. Notably: open both files with `open()` calls and use mode `'rb'` on the reader and `'wb'` on the writer. On the regular expressions change the `(\w+)` to just `(\w)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something that I think will do what you want. It's not as simple as Peter's answer because it uses Python's `csv` module to process the file. It could probably be rewritten and simplified to just treat the file as a plain text as his does, but that should be easy.

```
import csv
import re
import sys

csvdictreader = csv.DictReader(sys.stdin, delimiter=',')
csvdictwriter = csv.DictWriter(sys.stdout, fieldnames=csvdictreader.fieldnames, delimiter=',')
csvdictwriter.writeheader()
targets = [name for name in csvdictreader.fieldnames if name.startswith('HLA-')]

for rowfields in csvdictreader:
    keep = True
    for field in targets:
        value = rowfields[field]
        if re.match(r'^DQB1\*\d\d$', value): # gene resolution too low?
            keep = False
            break # quit processing target fields
        else: # reduce gene resolution if too high
              # by only keeping first two alles if three are present
            rowfields[field] = re.sub(r'^DQB1\*(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)$',
                                      r'DQB1*\1:\2', value)
    if keep:
        csvdictwriter.writerow(rowfields)
```

The hardest part for me was determining what you wanted to do.

Comment: When the python interpreter calls re.sub, the repl parameter gives an empty cell. How can I make it so that it will preserve the data given? I may have DRB1*01:02:02 or DQRB*05:03:01 or anything else of that type of format.

Comment: Also somewhere between the 1300th-1400th row, the program stops parsing the data and outputs the irrelevant information. Let me edit your post and add my code to the end of it.

Comment: The `\1` and `\2` in the `r'DQB1*\1:\2'` will preserve the digits matched by the first two `(\d\d)` parenthesized groups in the regex, however values starting with `DRB1*` or `DQRB*` wouldn't match the `DQRB` at the beginning of the pattern -- so the `re.sub()` call wouldn't do anything to them. That could be changed, but you need to be more clear in describing what the format (or pattern) of the data to be changed.

Comment: I can think of no likely reason for the script to start doing what you describe between the 1300th-1400th rows. You can print debugging information with `print >>sys.stderr, ...` statements. You should add any additional code to your question, not my answer.

Comment: Also I added a statement that says 
if rowfields > 1400:
    print >>sys.stderr

which gave me nothing

Comment: `rowfields` is not a row counter, it's a dictionary of fields created as each row of the file is read. A simple way to add a counter would be to change the outer loop to `for rownum, rowfields in enumerate(csvdictreader):` then check `if rownum > 1400:`.

Comment: You also have to put some variables or something on the line after the comma in the `print >>sys.stderr,` statement to tell it what you want output (just like a regular `print` statement).

Comment: I added the >>sys.stderr statement and only blank lines are being outputted onto the console.

Comment: That's becuase you have to put something else on the line after the `print >>sys.stderr,` part, like say `print >>sys.stderr, rowfields`. That still won't tell you the line number unless to put in my other suggestion of using `enumerate(csvdictreader)` and add `rownum` to the `print` statement as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an ultra-simple filter:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
  line = line.replace( ',DQB1*03:02:01,', ',DQB1*03:02,' )

  if line.find( ',DQB1*03,' ) == -1:
    sys.stdout.write( line )
```

Or, if you want to use regular expressions

```
import re
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
  line = re.sub( ',DQB1\\*03:02:01,', ',DQB1*03:02,', line )
  if re.search( ',DQB1\\*03,', line ) == None:
    sys.stdout.write( line )
```

Run it as

```
python script.py < data.csv
```

Comment: Even simpler would be to just do the `l.replace()` on every line.

Comment: you could iterate using: `for line in sys.stdin:`. Could you tell why do you use `.readlines()` here? [I'm interested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677270/how-to-read-from-a-file-using-only-readline#comment18775681_13677270)

Comment: you could use `if ',DQB1*03,' not in line: \n print line,` instead of `if line.find(...`. I don't know what `03:02` means but if `12:34` is also acceptable then you could use `\d\d:\d\d` in the regex. You could use `if not match:` or `if match is None:` instead of `if match == None`.