# Python Csv Parser only sorts through portion of file

Tags: python, parsing, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Filtering a CSV file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713752/filtering-a-csv-file-in-python)

I have a CSV parser written in python and it begins to fail around line 500. It begins to fail to parse the `^(\w+)\*(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)$` regex

```
import csv
import re
import sys

csvdictreader = csv.DictReader(open('mhc.csv','r+b'), delimiter=',')
csvdictwriter = csv.DictWriter(file('mhc_fixed.csv','w+b'), fieldnames=csvdictreader.fieldnames, delimiter=',')
csvdictwriter.writeheader()

targets = [name for name in csvdictreader.fieldnames if name.startswith('HLA-D')]

for rowfields in csvdictreader:
    keep = True

for field in targets:
    value = rowfields[field]

if re.match(r'^\w+\*\d\d$', value): # gene resolution too low?
  keep = False
  break # quit processing target fields

else: # reduce gene resolution if too high
    # by only keeping first two alles if three are present
    if (re.match(r'^(\w+)\*(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)$')): rowfields[field] = re.sub(r'^(\w+)\*(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)$',r'\1*\2:\3', value)

    if (re.match(r'^(\w+)\*(\d+):(\d+):(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)$')): rowfields[field] = re.sub(r'^(\w+)\*(\d+):(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)$',r'\1*\2:\3', value)

if keep:
    csvdictwriter.writerow(rowfields)

if rowfields > 1400:
    print >>sys.stderr
```

Comment: It's not uncommon to have problems parsing a CSV file. Try adding some print statements to your code so you can see the offending line and compare it to previous lines.

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your code. How do you know what line it's failing on? How is it failing? You didn't fix any of the items I mentioned to your other question [Filtering a CSV file in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713752/filtering-a-csv-file-in-python#comment18897827_13713752).

Comment: Don't open the file like that! You need to keep the file object so you can close it at the end... Or use "with"

Comment: @Alex: There's nothing wrong or difficult to parse with the `.csv` involved here.